# Ansible command to get yum history

Tags: awk, ansible, adhoc

Hello Ansible newbie here...I'm looking for an ansible way to get the last yum update date and write that out to a text file (later to be part of a web page).  I know the raw command:
`hostname && yum history | awk 'NR==5 { print $7, $8 }'`
and this works fine running from a regular bash shell (RHEL version 7 and 8), however, when I try to put this in an ansible ad-hoc command I get errors:

```
localhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
server: cmd. line:1: NR==5 { print ,  }
awk: cmd. line:1:               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==5 { print ,  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==5 { print ,  }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ unexpected newline or end of stringnon-zero return code
```

Any suggestions? I am guessing escaping may help but at this point I'm not sure what to escape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an Ansible ad hoc command to gather all information from all the hosts and consolidate it in a local file you have to escape the `$` in the `awk` command by prefixing them by a `\`.

```sh
ansible all -m ansible.builtin.shell -a \
       "hostname && yum history | awk 'NR==5 { print \$7, \$8 }'" \
       >> result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for an ansible way to get the last yum update date and write that out to a text file

```yaml
 - shell: "yum history | awk 'NR==5 { print $7, $8 }' >> /tmp/yum_history.txt"
   args:
     warn: false
```

Comment: I think the objective is to collect the history from several hosts and to write the result to a single file. This is why there is a `hostname` in the original command. Your proposal will write yum history in a file on each host.

Comment: Ah, that was unclear to me. I thought he was simply having issues with escaping quotes correctly and whatnot, thanks.

Comment: I wasn't very clear but I wanted this in an ad-hoc command.  @Romain, you are correct in that I want it to write 1 file on the server host that I'm running the command from - what would I need to do to to modify Kevin's answer to make that happen?  Thank you both BTW!